# Angular: how to style completed steps in PrimeNG p-steps component?

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to use the p-steps component in PrimeNG. I want to have different styling for the completed and not-completed steps. That is, if the user is currently at step 3, then step 1 & 2 are completed and I would like to set a background color green.
I noticed that PrimeNG 14 no longer supports p-steps-complete.

My implementation of the component is pretty basic:

```html
<p-steps
  #stepModule
  [model]="items"
  [readonly]="false"
  [activeIndex]="stepEvent.stepIndex">
</p-steps>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As PrimeNG 14 no longer supports p-steps-complete, the only chance is use css

Imagine in styles.css some like

```
.p-steps.completed-1 .p-steps-item:nth-child(-n + 1) .p-menuitem-link .p-steps-number,
.p-steps.completed-2 .p-steps-item:nth-child(-n + 2) .p-menuitem-link .p-steps-number,
.p-steps.completed-3 .p-steps-item:nth-child(-n + 3) .p-menuitem-link .p-steps-number,
.p-steps.completed-4 .p-steps-item:nth-child(-n + 4) .p-menuitem-link .p-steps-number
{
  background:red;
  color:white;
  border: 1px solid crimson;
}
```

In this way you can to have a variable "completed"

```
completed=0;
```

And your p-steps use `styleClass`

```
<p-steps [model]="items" 
         [(activeIndex)]="activeIndex" 
         [readonly]="false" 
         [styleClass]="'completed-'+completed">
</p-steps>
```

So, when you change the variable "completed" to 1,2,3 or 4 your see the styles applied

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-steps-demo-hcqdzm?file=src%2Fstyles.css)

**Updated** if we want the "active" not get the color we can use `:not(.p-highlight)`

```
.p-steps.completed-1 .p-steps-item:nth-child(-n + 1):not(.p-highlight) .p-menuitem-link .p-steps-number,
.p-steps.completed-2 .p-steps-item:nth-child(-n + 2):not(.p-highlight) .p-menuitem-link .p-steps-number,
.p-steps.completed-3 .p-steps-item:nth-child(-n + 3):not(.p-highlight) .p-menuitem-link .p-steps-number,
.p-steps.completed-4 .p-steps-item:nth-child(-n + 4):not(.p-highlight) .p-menuitem-link .p-steps-number
{
  background:red;
  color:white;
  border: 1px solid crimson;
}
```